# C# При обращении к процедуре ошибка PLS-00306

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

Собственно при таком раскладе происходит эта ошибка (см. вложения)
два варианта обращения к процедуре, с разным аргументом, необходимы по причине того, что так написана сама процедура. (тут как я понимаю костыль) , но он нужен.

Что необходимо сделать, чтобы не было этого исключения?

```
conn = db.GetDBConnection();
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                //данным способом обнуляется курсор в процедуре
                cmd.CommandText = "PROCEDURE";
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("nDEPT", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = 0;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("dDATE", OracleDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dat);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Cancel();
                conn.Close();


                //а так уже формируются нужные данные
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "PROCEDURE";
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("nDEPT", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = RN_INS;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("dDATE", OracleDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dat);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //вот тут начинает выдавать исключение
                cmd.Prepare();
                cmd.Cancel();
```

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Как процедура объявлена, покажите. Без этого ничего сказать нельзя.

Comment: вам же написано - число или типы аргументов. Сверяли определение вашей процедуры с параметрами, с которыми вы её вызываете?

Comment: Вызывать надо по имени процедуры, которое точно не  PROCEDURE, так как это ключевое слово.

Comment: "Вызывать надо по имени процедуры". Написано PROCEDURE для скрытия реального названия процедуры.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился так:

Просто надо очистить передаваемые параметры.

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```